# popping out an image outside overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="slider1" class="csslider infinity slider">
      <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_1" />
      <input type="radio" name="slides" checked="checked" id="slides_2" />
      <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_3" />
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="slider__content">
            <div class="slider__characteristics">
              <h3 class="heading--3 smallest-padding-bottom">
                head
              </h3>
              <p>
               text
              </p>
            </div>
            <img
              src="img/img.jpg"
              alt=""
              class="slider__img"
            />
          </div>
```

and this css:

```
.csslider > ul {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(
                      $light-bg-color, 0.4),
                      rgba($light-bg-color, 0.4));
  border-radius: .5rem;
  @include light-shadow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

 .csslider > ul > li {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: normal;
   padding: 2rem 2rem 0 2rem;
 }
 .slider__img {
        grid-column: 4 /  7;
        width: 105%;
        transform: rotate(-2deg);
        z-index: 200;

    }
```

I am trying to let the slider__img overflowing outside the slider but since the ul and the li have the overflow hidden i'm not able to find a solution.
How can i achieve this?
I have tried to set the ul and li to position static but nothing have changed.

Comment: As long as you are trying to use `slider__img` as selector, don’t expect _anything_ to happen …

Comment: ok... so which selector would you suggest to use?

Comment: Since you want to select elements by class, probably the class selector …

Comment: sorry...but i'm relatively new to this... could you be more specific please? i have tried to apply it to the class slider but it won't affect just  the image

Comment: `slider__img` and `.slider__img` are different things, is what I am trying to tell you …

Comment: sorry.. that was a typo... i'm using .slider__img